# Google Sheets ARRAYFORUMLA that can show 0 if the value is less than or equal to zero. Otherwise show the value of that set of data

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have set of columns that I am attempting to calculate the combined total of those columns then subtract from that total 8, if the difference after 8 is equal to or less than 0 I want to only show zero in the column I am doing this formula in. For those who might ask, I am using the `ARRAYFORUMLA` cause I want this calculation to repeat as I add new rows, keeping the totals I am seeking on the same row as the calculation is being done onto. So far I have most of this working. Well up to the IF ELSE THEN type of portion. My attempt is/was

```
=if(LTE((B3:B)+(C3:C)-8,0),ARRAYFORMULA((B3:B)+(C3:C)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I'm understanding you correctly, I believe this will work:

```
=if(lte(sum(B2:C)-8,0),0,sum(B2:C))
```

It's at the top of the row and sums columns B and C. You can add more columns easily this way by either changing B/C to something else or passing more columns in.

### Sum-8 is greater than 0

[image: Sum-8 is greater than 0]

### Sum-8 is less than 0

[image: Sum-8 is less than 0]

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to add each row to the total but only if its sum is 8 or greater, then your original formula was nearly OK but the two parts of the IF statement should have been reversed

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(if(LTE((B3:B)+(C3:C)-8,0),0,(B3:B)+(C3:C))))
```

You could also take most of the brackets out

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(if(LTE(B3:B+C3:C-8,0),0,B3:B+C3:C)))
```

and this would also work

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(if(LTE(B3:B+C3:C,8),0,B3:B+C3:C)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

> ARRAYFORMULA that can show 0 if the value is less than or equal to zero. Otherwise show the value of that set of data:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LTE(A1:A3,0),0,A1:A3))
```

## Explanation

The basic IF syntax requires the use of scalar values, to use it with arrays, ARRAYFORMULA is required as an outer function:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(array_logical_expression,array_if_true,array_if_false))
```

For the specific case described on the body of the question, the corresponding formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LTE(B3:B+C3:C-8,0),0,B3:B+C3:C))
```

## Reference

### Google Docs editors Help

- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)